# How to extract and remove selected variables from an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$var_array = array(
 "length"  => 5,
 "breadth"  => 5,
 "color" => "blue",
 "size"  => "medium",
 "shape" => "square");
```

How do I extract selected variables out of the array by specifying the keys?

Example if I specify `breadth` and `size`, I get:

```
$breadth = 5;
$size = "medium";
$var_array = array(
 "length"  => 5,
 "color" => "blue",
 "shape" => "square");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_diff_key`](http://php.net/array_diff_key) and [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key):

```
$array  = array(
  'breadth' => 1, 
  'size' => 2, 
  'length' => 3,
  'colour' => 4,
  'shape' => 5
);

$keys      = array('breadth', 'size');
$new_array = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($keys));
$array     = array_diff_key($array, $new_array);
```

Will produce:

```
// $new_array
array(2) {
 ["breadth"] => int(1)
 ["size"]    => int(2)
}

// $array
array(3) {
 ["length"] => int(3)
 ["colour"] => int(4)
 ["shape"]  => int(5)
}
```

If you want to put them into local variables you can do:

```
list($length, $colour, $shape) = array_values($new_array);
```

Or a less clear version:

```
extract($new_array);
```

Comment: Your edit is correct, but I can't seem to approve it, or edit the post myself anymore. Good catch though!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
$keys = array('breadth', 'size');  // which keys do you want to extract?

foreach($keys as $key) {
    $newArr[$key] = $var_array[$key];  // put'em in newArr
    unset($var_array[$key]);
}
extract($newArr);   // extract them to convert keys to variables
unset($newArr);   // unset newArr
```

Comment: you don't specify breadth and size, you only put them in an array

Comment: Your answer looks good. I am having a hard time looking at all the answers. Anyone care to vote the answers? Let me start voting yours.

Answer (score 0):

goldenparrot has already provided a good answer, but in case you want a solution that doesn't use foreach, you could use [array_intersect_key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) instead:

```
$var_array = array(...)
$keysToExtract = array('breadth', 'size');
extract(array_intersect_key($var_array, array_fill_keys($keysToExtract, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$var_array = array(
 "length"  => 5,
 "breadth"  => 5,
 "color" => "blue",
 "size"  => "medium",
 "shape" => "square");


reset($var_array);
$myarray =array();


while (list($key, $val) = each($var_array))
{
  if($key!='length' && $key!='size' )
  {
    $myarray[$key] =  $val;

  }else{

   echo "$key => $val<br />";

 }


}
```

output

```
size=> medium
breadth => 5

Array
(
    [color] => blue
    [length] => 5
    [shape] => square
)
```